# How to access .second in std::pair with std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm using MinGW64 with GCC 7.5.0 that enables C++17 on Dev C++ 5.11 on Windows 7.

Now how to access `.second` in the following `pair`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<pair<char,variant<bool,int,string>>> x;
    x.push_back(make_pair('i',5));
    cout<<x[0].first; //ok
    cout<<x[0].second; //error: no match for 'operator<<'
}
```

Comment: Simpler w/ the same problem: `variant<bool,int,string> v;(5); cout << v;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract a specific value from the variant based on type:

```
if(auto pval = std::get_if<int>(&x[0].second)) {
    std::cout << "variant has int value: " << *pval << '\n'; 
} else {
    std::cout << "failed to get int value!" << '\n'; 
}

if(auto pval = std::get_if<bool>(&x[0].second)) {
    std::cout << "variant has bool value: " << *pval << '\n'; 
} else {
    std::cout << "failed to get bool value!" << '\n'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::get` to retrive the object if you know its type.

```cpp
std::cout << std::get<int>(x[0].second)
```

If you don't know the type, use `std::visit` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing it correctly, it's just that `cout` doesn't know what to do with your particular `variant`. Either extract a specific type from it, or write a custom `operator <<` for the stream that does what you need it to do.

Comment: Can you please show me a small example or give me a lead about where to begin?

Comment: Example of getting data out of a `variant`? Use `std::get_if<T>`